# IllegalArgumentException: u'Data type StringType of column is not supported

Tags: pyspark

I need to perform linear Regression in Pyspark, I just tried to follow the steps of this link :

https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-linear-regression-with-pyspark-and-mllib-d065c3ba246a

In my case I just imported my data in data bricks using this code :

```py
## Importation de données

# File location and type
file_location = "/FileStore/tables/Spark.csv"
file_type = "csv"

# CSV options
infer_schema = "false"
first_row_is_header = "True"
delimiter = ","

# The applied options are for CSV files. For other file types, these will be ignored.
df = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .load(file_location)
```

Then I need to create an assembly vector having values of explaining variables without needed ones as the target, ID and _c0:

```py
ignore = ['ID', 'target', '_c0']
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=[x for x in df.columns if x not in ignore],
    outputCol='features')
```

My problem is when I use this command :

```py
new_df = vectorAssembler.transform(df)
```

It gives this error :

```py
IllegalArgumentException: u'Data type StringType of column is not supported
```

I am a beginner at Spark and searched many times, but i really can't understand the problem which is, because normally `vectorAssembler.transform` just add new single vector having selected variables to the initial data frame? No?? please help!

Comment: One of the columns in `inputCols` is a string. You need to convert to a numeric type before using `VectorAssembler`. You can look at `df.printSchema()` to see the data types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VectorAssembler does not support the StringType type scala spark convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527753/vectorassembler-does-not-support-the-stringtype-type-scala-spark-convert) and [How to use string variables in VectorAssembler in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332005/how-to-use-string-variables-in-vectorassembler-in-pyspark).